# .NET/C#: Is it possible to replace one object in memory with another?

Tags: c#, .net, object, reference, replace

Take this code for example:

```
class Jooky
{
    static long Last;
    public Jooky() { Id += Last++; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Flooky
{
    public Flooky() { Jooky1 = new Jooky(); Jooky2 = new Jooky(); }
    public Jooky Jooky1 { get; set; }
    public Jooky Jooky2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Flooky> Flookies = new List<Flooky>();

        //I build a collection of flookies to emulate the service call of
        //FlookyProxy.GetAllFlookies().
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Flookies.Add(new Flooky());

        //This makes a collection of all the jookies in all the flookies.
        var Jookies = Flookies.Select(f => f.Jooky1).Union(Flookies.Select(f => f.Jooky2));

        //I get the jooky.
        Jooky Jooky = Jookies.Single(j => j.Id == 2);

        //Fig 1: I just got a jooky out of the collection. One of the flookies
        //has a reference to this jooky. I want to set the jooky to a new
        //reference, but still want the same flooky to reference it.
        Jooky = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };

        //I get the jooky again
        Jooky = Jookies.Single(j => j.Id == 2);

        //However, this writes an empty string because only the Jooky variable
        //I previously declared was affected.
        Console.WriteLine(Jookies.Single(j => j.Id == 2).Name);

        //Basically, I want the code in Fig 1 above to be the same as:
        //Flooy.Jooky = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Basically, variable A is referencing Aa in memory and variable B is referencing object Bb in memory.  I want to make A reference the same object in memory as B without going like `A = B;`.  Instead, I want to replace the physical object in memory with another, ultimately going like `Aa = Bb;`.

Is this at all possible?

**Update:** Primary rule: I cannot reference the flooky directly, so I can't be all like `Flooky.Jooky1 = new Jooky()` or `Flookies[3].Jooky1 = new Jooky()`.

Comment: why do you want to do this - the clr handles a lot for you.

Comment: a `LinkedList` might do you some good too.

Comment: General comment: don't start local variable names wit a Capital.

Comment: And don't use naming conventions like in the last paragraph.

Comment: Daniel: A flooky has two jookies, Jooky1 and Jooky2.  I pull back a list of jookies from the database.  Now I have to assign all the flookies the proper jookies, so I get a jooky out of the collection of jookies that I got from all the flookies.  Since I don't have the flooky that had the jooky, I can't go like 'Flooky.Jooky1 = NewJookie;`.  I could get the flooky, but I wouldn't know whether Flooky.Jooky1 or Flooky.Jooky2 should get the new jooky.  However, if I could replace the reference item in memory directly, the flooky would now be referencing the new jooky.

Comment: Henk Holterman: Why not?

Comment: @oscilla General naming conventions. `Flooky Flooky` is used for properties.

Comment: What validation construct exists to make sure the programmer is following this convention? All my members (variables, properties, methods) use proper camel case (eg, EmployeeCount vs employeeCount). I am actually dogmatically opposed to using casing where the first word is lowercase.

Comment: Being allowed to do what you want to do would break encapsulation. The flooky is quite happy with the jooky it's currently got - the only way to change the flooky's jooky should be via **a message to the flooky** (eg method or property setter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is possible with unsafe code as suggested by havardhu, but it's definitely not possible with safe code. It's important to understand why doing what you're trying to do is unsafe. Not only does it break encapsulation, it breaks type safety. Consider this example.

```
class Me : IHaveCar
{
    BuickCentury myCentury = new BuickCentury(2004);

    public Car Car { get { return myCentury; } }

    public void Drive()
    {
        myCentury.CruiseWithAuthority();
    }
}

class EvilOilChangeService
{
    public void ChangeOil(IHaveCar customer)
    {
        Car car = customer.Car;
        // here's the fictional "replace object in memory" operator
        car <<== new VolkswagenBeetle(2003);
    }
}
```

The `EvilOilChangeService` can create a situation where `myCentury` is referencing a `VolkswagenBeetle`! I'm going to be in trouble when I try to go for a `Drive` because a `VolkswagenBeetle` just can't `CruiseWithAuthority` like a `BuickCentury` can (especially when the driver is 6'2")

Even in C/C++ which allows willy-nilly memory access, I would still be quite surprised by code that does what you want to do. This is why most of the other answers are suggesting a different approach or design.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
//Jooky = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };
Jooky.Name = "Bob" ;
```

The resullt of the `.Single()` is a *reference* to an instance (object). You were just overwriting the reference with one to a new object. The old object was not changed or overwritten.

To understand what's going on, and to adjust what you are aiming for, look up "Value Type and Reference Type". Lots of reading to do.

---

After reading the comment:

If your Details (Jookies) are going to change independently of their Owners (the Flookies) then you just need another layer of indirection.

A simple suggestion:

- do not store references to the details (since they will change)
- store a DetailId instead (JookyId1, JookyId2)
- keep the Details in a Dictionary (`Dictionary<int,Jooky>`)
- create a (readonly) property in Owner to get Detail1 by looking it up in the dictionary.

Comment: i think he wanted it to be changed to object 2.. not sure.. and this was probably an example

Comment: Yes, but the assumptions behind the question&example worry me.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. Read my example literally as if I am trying to replace one referenced object with another rather than just trying to set the name to Bob.

Comment: @oscilator: _Why_ would you want to do that? A: In .NET only by copying each field (property). Not recommended, rarely useful.

Comment: I explained in a response to Dan's comment beneath my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can write unsafe code in C# which enables you to operate on direct memory.

Have a look here for details:

[Pointers and arrays in C#](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Pointers-and-Arrays-in-C-sharp/)

You'll notice that you can use the familiar pointers (*) and addresses (&) from C and C++.

Here's an example of an unsafe swap, which I think is what you're after:
[Unsafe swap in C#](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0620__unsafe/Unsafeswap.htm)

Comment: I've been sitting here for the past hour trying to get this to work with my Jooky class, but, apparently, pointers only work with certain value types.  I even tried changing Jooky to a struct, but can't get it to work.  I am thinking it's not possible to do what I want to do, but I think you at least get the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
Jooky = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" }; 
Flookies[0].Jooky1=Jooky;
```

If you want to replace and object with another without just assigning references you just to copy all the data fields to the other object. Not sure if i have understood your question correctly.

Comment: You have to assume that I don't have the flooky.  All I have is the flooky's jooky.  I want to replace the jooky with new jooky instance without referencing the flooky at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with references, every assignment to a reference changes the object that reference points to.

So, when you say:

`Jooky Jooky = Jookies.Single(j => j.Id == 2);`

you're creating a **reference** to the Jookie with `Id == 2`. And then, when you say `Jooky = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };`, you're telling that reference you created to point to the Jooky you have just created instead.

So, if you want to set a new value to the `Jookie1` property (wich is a placeholder for a reference to a Jookie object) of the `Flookies[0]` object, you got to say:

`Flookies[0].Jooky1 = new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };` (as stated by @Ashley John's answer).

That way, you're telling the `Flookies[0].Jooky1` **reference** to point to the `new Jooky { Name = "Bob" };` object.

For further explanation, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx .

Comment: I definitely understand how references work in .NET.  I have a specific need to do this, the full scope would be too complicated to explain here.  The condition is (although I didn't state it in my question) is that I cannot reference the flooky directly.  Since you have the jooky variable, you obviously have the object it references in memory.  I am wondering if it's possible to replace the jooky in memory with a new jooky without touching the flooky.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that. But, if you have access to the `Jooky` class, you could add a property that holds the `Flookie` that is the parent of that `Jookie`, and then you'll have direct access to the `Flookie`.

Comment: But that would mean referencing the flooky which I can't do.  I am guessing it can't be done at this point, but I will research it a bit more,

Comment: I really don't see any way/why doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `Jookie` class, you could add a property that holds the parent `Flookie` of the `Jookie`:

```
class Jooky 
{
    static long Last;
    public Jooky(Flooky parent) 
    {
        Id += Last++; 
        Parent = parent;
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Flooky Parent { get; private set; }
}
```

and then access the parent `Flookie` and change it's `Jookie1` property:

```
Flookie flookie = Jookies.Single(j => j.Id == 2).Parent;
flookie.Jookie1 = new Jookie { Name = "Bob" }
```

Comment: This would require me reference the flooky.  I cannot do that in this particular scenario.  I updated my question with this just a bit ago.